# How can I display a fully rounded bar when the y-axis min is non-zero?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using the latest version of Chart.js (4.4.0).

I used `borderSkipped` and `borderRadius` to render a perfectly circular border, the same as in the official documentation.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/border-radius.html

Now, here's where I had a little trouble.

When I changed the minimum value of the Y axis from 0 to 1, the bottom side became flat as shown in the attached image.

How can I make it perfectly circular even if it is not 0?

[image: sample]

We tried setting various options to no avail.

It may be possible by using a plugin, but I would prefer an easy way if possible.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the library, where they are simply cropping the bar instead of recalculating its lower position when the min Y axis is changed. I'd suggest raising it with the developers.

Comment: The easiest way, I think, is to set [`base: 1`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#general) in the dataset (it's a scriptable option so you can also make it something like `base: ({chart}) => chart.scales.y.min || 0` if the y axis `min` value is dynamic); otherwise, the assumption is the that bar's `base` is at zero and the y axis `min` value  greater than 0 results in  the bars being cut above their `base`

Comment: @kikon
`base` solved the problem perfectly.
Thank you for your comment.